# Add different class to every 7 elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a blog page with a list of posts. Each blog post has the same html for example:

```
<article class="post">
  post 1
</article>
```

I want to give every 7 articles a sequence of classes ('medium','small','large','large','small','small','medium')

```
<article class="post medium">
  post 1
</article>
<article class="post small">
  post 2
</article>
<article class="post large">
  post 3
</article>
<article class="post large">
  post 4
</article>
```

When I post blog number 8 it starts all over. Is this even possible?

Any points to the right direction would be very welcome!

Comment: How are you creating the `<article>`'s?  It might be better to do it server side, unless you're creating this through an AJAX request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the addClass and check its index:

```
var classNames = ['medium','small','large','large','small','small','medium'];

$('article.post').addClass(function(i){
    return classNames[ i % classNames.length ];
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wgdv4/

Comment: Works like a charm! Never thought about using .length.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using **CSS3 selectors** - I know it's tagged JavaScript but you are already using HTML5 so you might as well. Honestly, it will save you loads of time compared to writing out a pure JS or JQuery function: anytime you can get away with not using JavaScript you should. Anyway, look into selectors [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

This changes the class of the first node in a set, then the 8th, then 15th etc. to post medium, and continued in the same fashion but with 2nd, 9th etc for post small and so on.

```
ul li:nth-child(1n+7) {  
  class: "post medium";
}

ul li:nth-child(2n+7) {  
  class: "post small";
}
```

Comment: Not a bad solution considering it's HTML5 being used.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `class` CSS rule?  I've never heard of it, and it doesn't appear to work like you demonstrate.  http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/AGmBh/

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery this can be done in the following way:

```
var classes = ["medium", "small", "large", "large", "small", "small", "medium"];
$(".post").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(classes[i % classes.length]);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DCYjF/

Answer (score 2):

```
var klasses = ['medium','small','large','large','small','small','medium'];

$('article.post').each(function( index)
{
$(this).addClass( klasses[index % klasses.length] );
});
```

This will itereate over your posts, using the `index` variable to pull from `klasses`, which is an array of your classes.  When it reaches the 'end' of your `klasses` array, it starts over, thanks to the `%` operator.

Edit: looks like a lot of us went with the similar solution.  Just one thing to note is that this solution uses .length as an indicator of how many items instead of a hardcoded 7.  I don't care if you don't accept this answer, but I would recommend using length, that way you can add/remove classes without having to change your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the mod operator- (%). Doing (n % 7 == 0) will return true if n is divisible cleanly by 7 (where n is the id of the current post) ,you can use this to reset your style count.